# Get taxonomy used for each year in a view

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I created a view that list how many time a taxonomy terms (tags) was used on (articleS on) my site.

```
tag1  (236)   
tag2  (200)    
tag3  (157)    
tag4  (161)   
tag5  (10)    
tag6  (90)
tag7  (86)   
tag8  (50)    
tag9  (15)
```

How can I modify that view to show how many time a taxonomy is used each year?

```
2016     
tag1  (150)   
tag2  (100)    
tag3  (75)    
tag4  (36)
tag6  (20)
2015  
tag4  (125) 
tag6  (70)      
tag1  (50)
tag3  (50)      
tag2  (45)       
tag5  (10)
2014
tag7  (86)
tag2  (55)  
tag1  (36)  
tag3  (32)   
tag8  (30)    
tag9  (15)
```

Or any time interval? if possible.

**update**
Here is an image of my view setting
[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% if that might be the solution to your issue but in your View, you can add the article's publish date (exclude from display), also go to View's settings and add grouping by publish date (sort the results appropriately too). Would that work?

Comment: @webmaniac, thanks for your suggestion but it does not work. I've added an image hope it will give more insight.

Comment: removing the aggregation (in other) and checking off Require this relationship (in relationship) Will give me a yearly results (2016 on image) But not the result wanted.

Comment: Have you selected the date as your grouping field under Format > Settings?

Comment: I know this might be a bad idea. But if you have to do this, adding php code is always a choice for you. (Unless everything doesn't work and you have to do this)